# Substring all letters in a string between two characters

Tags: r, regex

I could not find a solution for this quickly by looking online. I simply need to grab the substring that exists between the `$` and the `.` in the string below:

```
a = "NBA_FINAL_ONCOURT$2016012523.XML"
```

I read solutions using some complex combinations of `substr` and `gregexpr`, that didn't necessarily give me what I needed.

All I want to do is return `"2016012523"`.

Comment: Many ways of achieving this, for instance `sub(".*\\$(.*)\\..*", "\\1", a)`. You need to learn some regex

Comment: indeed i do. regex is the go to for string manipulation?

Comment: In most cases yes, in your case you could also do something like `strsplit(a, "\\$|\\.")[[1]][2]` in order to avoid it. But you will have to figure out how to vectorize it afterwards. Though if you have `data.table` installed you could easily vectorize it using something like `data.table::tstrsplit(a, "\\$|\\.", keep = 2)[[1]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex with `regmatches`/`regexpr`:

```
> a = "NBA_FINAL_ONCOURT$2016012523.XML"
> regmatches(a, regexpr("(?<=\\$)[^.]+", a, perl=TRUE))
[1] "2016012523"
```

The regex is pretty easy:

- `(?<=\\$)` - there must be a literal `$` before the currently analyzed location
- `[^.]+` - one or more (`+`) chars other than `.` (a `.` inside `[...]` matches a literal `.`).

**NOTE**: to require a dot, you need to append a `(?=\\.)` lookahead: `(?<=\\$)[^.]+(?=\\.)`

If you want to use a TRE regex (default flavor), you may use the same pattern with the lookbehind `(?<=\\$)` changed into a capturing group, a `(...)` (but then, to access that value, you need to use `regmatches` with `regexec`:

```
> regmatches(a, regexec("\\$([^.]+)", a))[[1]][2]  ## or "\\$([^.]+)\\." to require a dot
[1] "2016012523"
```

Note that here `[^.]+` is wrapped with capturing parentheses that form a subgroup in the regex match object and you can acces that subgroup later.

Or do it with `sub` as [David commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666256/substring-all-letters-in-a-string-between-two-characters#comment72457707_42666256) to match the whole string, capture what you need with the capturing group, and replace with the backreference to the subtext captured:

```
> sub(".*\\$([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", a)
[1] "2016012523"
```

Here,

- `.*` - matches any 0+ chars, as many as possible up to the last occurrence of the subpatterns to follow
- `\\$` - a literal `$` (otherwise, it matches the end of the string)
- `([^.]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `.`
- `\\.` - a literal dot
- `.*`  - the rest of the string.

Answer (score -1):

It depends how your string is coming either it is dynamic or it is static.
If it is static then it is simple you can directly replace those text but if it is dynamic then you have to write some stuffs.For eg.

```
String a="NBA_FINAL_ONCOURT$2016012523.XML";
String []b=a.split("T");//spliting string into 2 parts
String k=b[1].replace("$","").replace(".XML","");//removing remaining text

If your value is dynamic then plz use :StringTokenizer
```